# I'm confused about the use of normalizing a path in Python

Tags: python, operating-system

I've read that normalizing file paths allows a script to run on any operating system. Suppose I have the following script that opens a file called hello.txt

```
import os
os.path.normpath(os.getcwd())
a= open("hello.txt","r")
b= a.read()
print(b)
```

Will this script now be able to run on any os if I send the script in a folder to someone, with the `hello.txt` file in the same folder? Or do I have to do something else

Comment: You don't need normalization here. In fact , you are discarding the result

Comment: Why do you think it does this? It might be needed if you're working with some random program that *demands* qualified paths use the OS standard directory separators, but most APIs don't care (forward slashes work fine on Windows for most purposes). As is, your `normpath` is doing *nothing* because you don't assign the result, but you didn't need to do anything anyway when you're operating on a file in the working directory anyway.

Comment: Please look up what normalization really does before deciding if you need it.

Comment: So you mean nothing will print out? Also, could you please explain why I don't need normalisation. Thanks

Comment: `normpath` returns a string and has no other side-effects. Since the returned string is discarded, it is not used. Anyway, [`normpath` does that the documentation claims](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html): "Normalize a pathname by collapsing redundant separators and up-level references.." which is not very useful here. It would be useful if wishing to build a 'prettier' path for display, eg. '/foo/bar/../x.txt' and '/foo/x.txt' represent the same file; the latter path has been "normalized".

Comment: @user2864740 Thanks i understand it better now. So in what sort of cases would there be a need for normpath?

Comment: @ShadowRanger so even if I was sending the script to someone using a different OS it will still work?

Comment: @West I'm not immediately coming up with a case for of why one would "need" normpath, per-se.. in cases of a canonical path, abspath would often be a better candidate. It can definitely make showing paths shorter and more human-friendly. (Note how abspath can be written using normpath + getcwd, was this the original intent..?)

Comment: @user2864740 Ok so I suppose if I put the txt file in a different folder from the script then normpath could be required? How would I create the abspath using getcwd + normpath.

Comment: @West `normpath` still wouldn't be required: you just have to use a path that point to a valid file in `open`. ie. the file `".././foo.txt"` to `open` *refers* to the the same file as `normpath(getcwd() + "/x/../../" + "foo.txt")`. Python doesn't care - this is just how file paths are resolved.

Comment: @user2864740 Well explained. Thanks